# Is it possible to create three different condtions in LINQ with three different results?

Tags: c#, linq

**Below is my Lambda LINQ.**

```
return await _trialBalanceContext
    .Entries
    .Select(x => new
    {
        accountTitle = x.AccountTitle,
        debitAmount = x.DebitAmount,
        creditAmount = x.CreditAmount,
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

**And I want to apply this conditions below in my LINQ above.**

```
if (accountTitle == "Asset"){
    debitAmount = debitAmount * 100
    creditAmount = creditAmount * 100
 } else if (accountTitle == "Expense"){
    debitAmount = debitAmount - creditAmount
    creditAmount = creditAmount * debitAmount
 } else 
 {
    debitAmount = creditAmount + 30
    creditAmount = debitAmount + 50
 }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: `creditAmount = creditAmount * debitAmount` Does the `debitAmount` refer to the **original** value or the value assigned on the line immediately prior?

Comment: original value.
thanx for reply!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
return await _trialBalanceContext
    .Entries
    .Select(x => new
    {
        accountTitle = x.AccountTitle,
        debitAmount = (x.AccountTitle == "Asset") ? x.DebitAmount*100 : ((x.AccountTitle == "Expense") ? x.DebitAmount - x.CreditAmount : x.CreditAmount + 30),
        creditAmount = (x.AccountTitle == "Asset") ? x.CreditAmount*100 : ((x.AccountTitle == "Expense") ? x.CreditAmount * x.DebitAmount : x.DebitAmount + 50),
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: That's close but will not compile, because you cannot reference `accountTitle` when you set `debitAmount` and `creditAmount`.

Comment: Is there any way to reference my accountTitle?

Comment: @AhcmadAngagao do you mean pass titles as variable?